# Hive: Format string to look like phone number

Tags: hive, string-formatting

I have phone numbers saved as text in a column of my table. How can i format it to look like some phone number format using hive.

```
Phone number    Formatted
2076234568      207-623-4568
2079425555      207-942-5555
3178723275      317-872-3275
2072367033      207-236-7033
2077832249      207-783-2249
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select  Phone_number
       ,regexp_replace(Phone_number,'(.{3})(.{3})(.{4})','$1-$2-$3')    as Formatted
from    t
;
```

---

```
+---------------+---------------+
| phone_number  |   formatted   |
+---------------+---------------+
| 2076234568    | 207-623-4568  |
| 2079425555    | 207-942-5555  |
| 3178723275    | 317-872-3275  |
| 2072367033    | 207-236-7033  |
| 2077832249    | 207-783-2249  |
+---------------+---------------+
```